# Photon detecting if a player is already in that spawn position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, photon

I have 3 players in a room, and 3 set spawn positions, but would like each player to be spawned in one of these positions and not on the same position. I've got this, but how can I make sure that another player won't also spawn in this spawnpoint?

```
number = UnityEngine.Random.Range(1, 3);


if (number == 1)
{    
     spawnpoint = GameObject.FindWithTag("spawnpoint1");
}


if (number == 2)
{
     spawnpoint = GameObject.FindWithTag("spawnpoint2");
}

if (number == 3)
{
     spawnpoint = GameObject.FindWithTag("spawnpoint3");
}

GameObject myPlayer = PhotonNetwork.Instantiate(playerprefabname, spawnpoint.transform.position, spawnpoint.transform.rotation, 0);
```

Comment: You could add all 3 spawn points to a set, and shuffle the set. Then iterate over the set spawning your players. This would give you a random-ish set of unique spawn points. Just as long as you don't use the same element twice, it should give each player a unique spawn point.

Answer (score 0):

Put the list of available spawn positions in a stack; when you need a new position pop the item off the stack and use that spawn positions.

You need to ensure that you have more spawn positions than players -- obviously.

And you also probably want to somehow randomize the stack each time.

You can take the concept and use any data structure you'd like but the important idea is to remove the "consumed" element until you are ready to reset.

Comment: Thanks, will have to figure out how to do that now :P

Answer (score 0):

You could create an array of spawn points, and randomize them and spawn your object there. With this method you can have as many spawn points as you want without having to change the code.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Linq;

public class Test : MonoBehaviour {

    [SerializeField] Vector3[] spawnPoints;
    [SerializeField] GameObject spawnObject;


    void Start(){
        InitRandom ();
    }

    void InitRandom(){
        System.Random rnd = new System.Random ();
        Vector3[] items = (
            from i in spawnPoints
            orderby rnd.Next()
            select i
        ).ToArray();

        foreach (Vector3 v in items) {
            Instantiate(spawnObject, v, Quaternion.identity);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try getting the number of players connected to a room and use that number to select the particular spawn point.

Something like this -

```
var playerID = PhotonNetwork.otherPlayers.Length;
var player = PhotonNetwork.Instantiate(name, spawns[playerID].transform.position, spawns[playerID].transform.rotation, 0);
player.name = "Player " + (playerID + 1);
```